# CSH variable with spaces bring broke up when passed to another script

Tags: csh, tcsh

I am passing a variable (with spaces inside of single quotes) as parameters to another csh script, but it is splitting them up in the second script.  If I manually run the same line in tcsh, it works.

spacetest.csh:

```
#!/bin/csh -vx
set SERVER = "UAT"
set SUBJECT = "'Test Report $SERVER'"
set MESSAGE = "testmessage.msg"
set ATTACHMENTS = "'-a file1.csv -a file2.csv'"
emailtest.csh $SUBJECT $MESSAGE $ATTACHMENTS
```

emailtest.csh:

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "1 $1"
echo "2 $2"
echo "3 $3"
```

Since I am using -vx, it is showing what the parameters look like, but it is still splitting them up.

Output includes:

```
/scratch/hr-finance/scripts/emailtest.csh $SUBJECT $MESSAGE $ATTACHMENTS
/scratch/hr-finance/scripts/emailtest.csh 'Test Report UAT' testmessage.msg '-a file1.csv -a file2.csv'
1 'Test
2 Report
3 UAT'
```

Now if I copy-and-paste the line and run it in tcsh, it works as expected.

```
%emailtest.csh 'Test Report UAT' testmessage.msg '-a file1.csv -a file2.csv'
1 Test Report UAT
2 testmessage.msg
3 -a file1.csv -a file2.csv
%
```

If I try something with `\"` instead, I get an Unmatched double quote error:

```
%set SUBJECT = "\"Test Report $SERVER\""
Unmatched ".
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix was to use "eval".

```
eval /scratch/hr-finance/scripts/CM_MAIL.csh $SUBJECT $MESSAGE $ATTACHMENTS
```